# Find all functions for which their inverse equals the derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives, inverse-function, golden-ratio

I was wondering how you could find all functions $f$ for which it holds true that $f^{-1} = f'$.

I found the solution $\varphi^{1-\varphi}x^{\varphi}$ for which this holds true. Are there any other solutions and is there a closed form for all solutions for this equation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3312572/42969

Comment: see "2.) Non-Existence of Non-elementary Integrals" in my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3095196/functions-that-are-easy-to-antidifferentiate-but-whose-inverses-are-hard-to-anti/3095634#3095634

Comment: Your class is not correct, since for $\phi\equiv\,1$ we get $f(x)=x$ which does not satisfy the condition, because $f'(x)=1$ and $f^{-1}(x)=x$

Comment: @Oxff: Trying to make sense of this An inverse function is a points set. The derivative is a single value found at a given point in the function set.

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos, Phi here denotes the golden ratio, not an arbitrary parameter, and the given example does work.

Comment: ΟΚ you should have clarified that!